# Connecting a PS/2-to-USB keyboard to Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, usb, hid, ps2

I have a lovely ancient ergonomic keyboard (no name SK - 6000) connected via a [DIN-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector#Other_uses)-to-[PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) adapter to a PS/2-tp-USB adapter to my docking station.  After [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB), it stops working. It takes either suspending and waking up or replugging it while Linux is running to get it to work.  No extra kernel modules get loaded for this.  When it works and I restart without power off, it will work immediately.

Even when it does **not** work, it is visible (the [lsusb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lspci#lsusb) device number varies, but the output is identical whether working or not):

```
lsusb -v -s 001:006

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a81:0205 Chesen Electronics Corp. PS/2 Keyboard+Mouse Adapter
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x0a81 Chesen Electronics Corp.
  idProduct          0x0205 PS/2 Keyboard+Mouse Adapter
  bcdDevice            0.10
  iManufacturer           1 CHESEN
  iProduct                2 PS2 to USB Converter
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
bLength                 9
bDescriptorType         2
wTotalLength           59
bNumInterfaces          2
bConfigurationValue     1
iConfiguration          2 PS2 to USB Converter
bmAttributes         0xa0
  (Bus Powered)
  Remote Wakeup
MaxPower              100mA
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        0
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
  bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
  bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
  iInterface              0 
    HID Device Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType        33
      bcdHID               1.10
      bCountryCode            0 Not supported
      bNumDescriptors         1
      bDescriptorType        34 Report
      wDescriptorLength      64
     Report Descriptors: 
       ** UNAVAILABLE **
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            3
      Transfer Type            Interrupt
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
    bInterval              10
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
  bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
  bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
  iInterface              0 
    HID Device Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType        33
      bcdHID               1.10
      bCountryCode            0 Not supported
      bNumDescriptors         1
      bDescriptorType        34 Report
      wDescriptorLength     148
     Report Descriptors: 
       ** UNAVAILABLE **
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
    bmAttributes            3
      Transfer Type            Interrupt
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
    bInterval              10
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)


ll -R /sys/bus/hid/drivers/

/sys/bus/hid/drivers/:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jul  8  2012 generic-usb/

/sys/bus/hid/drivers/generic-usb:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  7 23:33 0003:046D:C03D.0003 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.2/1-1.2.2:1.0/0003:046D:C03D.0003/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  7 23:33 0003:0A81:0205.0001 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0001/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  7 23:33 0003:0A81:0205.0002 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.1/0003:0A81:0205.0002/
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Jul  7 23:32 bind
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  7 23:33 module -> ../../../../module/usbhid/
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Jul  7 23:32 new_id
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Jul  8  2012 uevent
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Jul  7 23:32 unbind
```

When replugging, [dmesg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg) shows this (which except for the first line and different input numbers already came at boot time):

```
[ 1583.295385] usb 1-1.2.1: new low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[ 1583.446514] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/input/input17
[ 1583.446817] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2.1/input0
[ 1583.454764] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.1/input/input18
[ 1583.455534] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2.1/input1
[ 1583.455578] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[ 1583.455584] usbhid: USB HID core driver
```

So I tried

```
sudo udevadm test /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0001/hidraw/hidraw0

run_command: calling: test
adm_test: version 175
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program,
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/40-crda.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/40-fuse.rules' as rules file
...
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb-media-players.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules' as rules file
...
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/42-qemu-usb.rules' as rules file
...
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules' as rules file
add_rule: IMPORT found builtin 'usb_id', replacing /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules:76
...
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-device-blacklist.rules' as rules file
...
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/85-usbmuxd.rules' as rules file
...
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-hid.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-wup.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules' as rules file
udev_rules_new: rules use 271500 bytes tokens (22625 * 12 bytes), 44331 bytes buffer
udev_rules_new: temporary index used 76320 bytes (3816 * 20 bytes)
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x7f78a5e4d2d0 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0001/hidraw/hidraw0'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x7f78a5e5f820 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0001/hidraw/hidraw0'
udev_device_read_db: device 0x7f78a5e5f820 filled with db file data
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x7f78a5e60270 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0001'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x7f78a5e609c0 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x7f78a5e61160 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x7f78a5e61960 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x7f78a5e62150 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x7f78a5e62940 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x7f78a5e630f0 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0'
udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x7f78a5e638a0 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00'
udev_event_execute_rules: no node name set, will use kernel supplied name 'hidraw0'
udev_node_add: creating device node '/dev/hidraw0', devnum=251:0, mode=0600, uid=0, gid=0
udev_node_mknod: preserve file '/dev/hidraw0', because it has correct dev_t
udev_node_mknod: preserve permissions /dev/hidraw0, 020600, uid=0, gid=0
node_symlink: preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/251:0' to '../hidraw0'
udev_device_update_db: created empty file '/run/udev/data/c251:0' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0001/hidraw/hidraw0'
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw0
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0001/hidraw/hidraw0
MAJOR=251
MINOR=0
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw
UDEV_LOG=6
USEC_INITIALIZED=969079051
```

The later lines sound like it's already there.  And none of these awakes the keyboard:

```
sudo udevadm trigger --verbose --sysname-match=usb*

/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usbmon/usbmon1
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usbmon/usbmon2
/sys/devices/virtual/usbmon/usbmon0

sudo udevadm trigger --verbose --sysname-match=hidraw0

/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0001/hidraw/hidraw0

sudo udevadm trigger
```

I also tried this to no avail (as super user):

```
echo -n 0003:0A81:0205.0001 > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/generic-usb/bind
ksh: echo: write to 1 failed [No such device]

echo -n 0003:0A81:0205.0001 > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/generic-usb/unbind

echo -n 0003:0A81:0205.0001 > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/generic-usb/bind

echo usb1 >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind

echo usb1 >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```

What else should I try to get the same result as replugging or suspending, by just issuing a command?

Comment: You need to post this question at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Probably not it, but one thing you might check is the electrical current rating of the PS/2 adapter. You can see this by running `lsusb -v` and looking for "MaxPower" of the appropriate device. I think max current for PS/2 is supposed to be 275 mA. USB can be 0 - to 500 mA, depending on configuration requested by the adapter. Oh, and another thing you might try is plugging it into a self-powered hub and seeing if it reproduces.

Comment: just for completeness same - fat old plug is called DIN9. I've not seen one since my old xt tho ;p

Comment: 2012, the year of the desktop linux.

Comment: Oh, its not linux's fault. Its very likely just the darned setup being so convoluted. I VAGUELY seem to think startup voltages are at fault here, but thats just unfounded gut instinct.

Comment: Just kidding. Same happens to my old Razer mouse. (Never buy a Razer people. Never!)

Answer (score 1):

here the solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48792/how-to-enable-an-extern-keyboard-using-ps2-to-usb-adapter-on-a-notebook

there are 2 kinds of this adapters:
the first one simply changes one plug for another,
the other one works on signals.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue too.

Solution (not sure about the root cause, but this worked for me):

1. Detach the PS2-to-USB from Laptop.
2. Detach the keyboard & mouse.
3. Just attach the PS2-to-USB back to laptop, then plug the keyboard and mouse in. Starts working. Root cause is not known.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the BIOS can see the keyboard and mouse just fine if it is working in GRUB.  I have a suggestion that might perhaps sound counter intuitive.  If your BIOS has the option then enable PS/2 keyboard and mouse emulation.  What this does is has a chip on the motherboard interrupt the USB signals from any USB HID devices and translate that into their equivalent PS/2 devices for the operating system to see.  This feature was quite common as motherboard manufacturers was trying to minimize port counts while still keeping people happy that were running operating systems that didn't have full support of USB.

Emulating PS/2 devices on the motherboard while using a PS/2 to USB adapter does mean a double translation to back to where you started but it might just work.  It might be that the adapter is losing something in translation that the USB drivers don't understand but the BIOS gets just fine.  So, let the BIOS do the work instead.

Another option is to try USB-to-serial adapters and the PS/2 on serial port drivers.  I've had luck with old PS/2 mice on serial ports with Windows and Linux but haven't really tried keyboards.  You will need a halfway working keyboard or something to set this up, which it sounds like you have.  If you have a serial port and/or USB to serial adapters then give that a try.

Before going down the path of a keyboard on a serial port I'd suggest the BIOS emulation, it's much easier and far more likely to work, and easily reversible if it doesn't.  Serial port mice and keyboard on the other hand may be trivial, maybe not.

Answer (score -1):

With very unstable behaviours from both PS/2 keyboard (wild repeating keys, mixed with, vertical cursor movements both up and down) utter chaos when trying to edit a config file! Also unstable PS/2 mouse configuration and action of mouse keys altering at each  re-connection making the GUI and web-browser generally unusable!

Good call: Drawing attention to the use of a powered USB hub, 5 Amp power supply output for a 7 port (5 direct + 2 intermittent charging) USB hub in my case has solved all the errant behaviours in one action. Plus the ability to connect a large capacity 2.5" HDD via USB by observing the same power requirement for each connected device and keeping everything within the 5 Amp total again in this case.

(I searched for this topic on the basis of having both PS/2 mouse and keyboard with a PS/2 x2 female connectors to, a USB x1 male connector, cable connected adaptor. This adaptor I have had ever since USB began to take over from PS/2 and I find it still useful with an original IBM labelled heavy duty claketty-clack keyboard and fortunately an optical 3 button wheelie-mouse. Never throw anything away. IT will always revive an opportunity for cheaper usage! That is even when everybody has forgotten about the different power requirements of old and new tech' and the consequences)

Thank you.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The powered USB hub part may refer to [Stephen Niedzielski's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/446293/connect-ps-2-usb-keyboard-to-linux#comment517446_446293) to the question.

Comment: See also *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*